# Docker databse initialisation in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d no access to enviroment variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-secrets

I have an influx db image (bitnami/influxdb:2.6.1-debian-11-r34) and a mariadb image (mariadb:10.7.6-focal).
Both allow to run initial setup by placing scripts in to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` dir.

**MariaDB**

> Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions .sh, .sql, .sql.gz, .sql.xz and .sql.zst that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. .sh files without file execute permission are sourced rather
> than executed. You can easily populate your mariadb services by
> mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with
> contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the
> database specified by the MARIADB_DATABASE / MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

**Influx**

> Initializing a new instance
>
> When the container is executed for the first time, it will execute the
> files with extensions .sh, and .txt located at
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d.
>
> In order to have your custom files inside the docker image you can
> mount them as a volume.

My goal is to place a script there that is creating a user with read only permissions.
My problem is that the scripts that I place in those dirs (`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`) have neither access to the environment variables nor the secrets set in the docker swarm file.

I set the secrets like so:

```
secrets:
   - influx_admin_token
environment:
   - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN_FILE=/run/secrets/influx_admin_token
```

And the environment variables and the secrets work fine when I open en interactive `/bin/bash` with the `-it` flags in the container.

script that I placed in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (influx example):

```bash
echo $INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN_FILE
echo $(<$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN_FILE)
echo $(< /run/secrets/influx_admin_token)
```

the script is executed but cant see the environment variable nor the existence of the secrets file.

What do I need to change to get access to the environment variables and secrets.

Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338477/docker-secrets-environment-variables-only-available-in-it-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I finally figured out what is happening:
The entry point scripts of both containers take variables `$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN_FILE` and read the given file and create `$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN` from that and delete the original (`$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER_TOKEN_FILE`) variable.

However this only seems to happen for some predefined variables.

Put `printenv` in the script to see whats happening.

influx: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/influxdb/2/debian-11/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/influxdb-env.sh#L22

mariadb: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/mariadb-galera-swarm/blob/master/start.sh#L194